# Find all sales made by each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench

I am trying to list all the sales, which links with a customer ID, so I expect to see

```
sale ID    customerID    customerfirstname    customerlastname 
1          1             J                    Bloggs
2          2             G                    Green
3          1             J                    Bloggs
```

This is all I have no far and it's not quite right...

```
SELECT  sale.sale_id
        customer.customer_id ,
        customer.customer_first_name , 
        customer.customer_last_name , 
FROM mydb.customer , mydb.sale
WHERE sale.sale_id = customer_id
```

Here is my structure

```
CREATE TABLE `sale` (
  `sale_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_items` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sale_paid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sale_id`,`customer_customer_id`),
  KEY `fk_sale_customer1_idx` (`customer_customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sale_customer1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address3` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_post_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_debit` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please share your tables' structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining on the wrong field - both tables have a column referencing the customer id, which you should use. Additionally, you have a redundant comma after the last item in the select list and are missing one after the first item:

```
SELECT  sale.sale_id,
        customer.customer_id,
        customer.customer_first_name, 
        customer.customer_last_name
FROM    customer, sale
WHERE   sale.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Note, however, that using implicit joins (i.e., having more than one table in the `from` clause) is deprecated and discouraged, and you should probably use **explicit** joins instead:

```
SELECT  sale.sale_id,
        customer.customer_id,
        customer.customer_first_name, 
        customer.customer_last_name
FROM    customer
JOIN    sale ON sale.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Using the second one

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `JOIN` to connect the tables.
from looking at your tables, it looks like `customer_customer_id` is the column on `sale` table that matches the customer id:

```
SELECT  sale.sale_id
        customer.customer_id ,
        customer.customer_first_name , 
        customer.customer_last_name 
FROM customer INNER JOIN sale on 
sale.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Comment: it's saying the `.` in `customer.customer_id` is unexpected?

Comment: @Badja - it can work with only `customer_id`, without the table name, as this column name does not appear on the other table, so it's not ambiguous. In my mind, it's better to add the table name. makes it more readable

Answer (score 2):

You should join customer id on customer id, not on sale id.

```
SELECT  sale.sale_id,
        customer.customer_id ,
        customer.customer_first_name , 
        customer.customer_last_name 
FROM mydb.customer INNER JOIN mydb.sale ON sale.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Comment: and also a redundant comma after `customer.customer_last_name` in the select segment

Comment: it's saying the `.` in `customer.customer_id` is unexpected?

Comment: @Badja since all answers have the same query, I guess you made a mistake when you tried to implement my or Nir's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your structure it should be something like:

```
SELECT  s.sale_id
        s.customer_id ,
        c.customer_first_name , 
        c.customer_last_name , 
FROM 
  mydb.customer c
INNER JOIN
  mydb.sale s
ON 
  s.customer_id = c.customer_id
```